# Isoperimetric inequality

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, minimal-surfaces

[image]

I'm trying to understand a lemma from [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1988-310-01/S0002-9947-1988-0965747-6/S0002-9947-1988-0965747-6.pdf). In my understanding, it says that

1. Since $M$ is closed, there exists $\alpha>0$ and a map $\phi:M\to \mathbb{R}^n$ (with some property that I am not familiar with) such that $\phi (B_M(x,\alpha))=B_{\mathbb{R}^n}(\mathbf{0},1) $. What is this map?
2. For any closed curve $\gamma$ on the boundary of $B_{\mathbb{R}^n}(\mathbf{0},1)$, the area of $D'=\mathbf{0}\circledast \gamma$, the cone over $\gamma$ with respect to the origin, is less or equal than the square of the length of $\gamma$. Is there any way to prove this using some integral?

Comment: This is called the exponential map. You can find details in any Riemannian Geometry textbook.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I read about the exponential map, and it's a map between $T_pM$ and $M$, but I thought that the map $\phi$ should be from $M$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Or, I'm wrong? Thanks

Comment: This is the inverse map, with $\Bbb R^n$ the tangent space.